# Can't boot Windows 7 after Ubuntu installation

Tags: dual-boot

I've tried to install Ubuntu on a separate partition along with windows 7,  but, after that, Windows 7 doesn't boot due to a disk error problem. 
Suggest solution such that both OSs boot perfectly.

Comment: Does Ubuntu boot OK?  As for Windows not booting try [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).